# Parse Azure Blob Content-MD5

Tags: python, ruby, azure, md5

The following block is what the Azure Blob storage returns when requesting a listing of a container in XML format.

```
<Blob>
  <Name>commits-dump.2015-10-03.tar.gz</Name>
  <Url>https://ghtstorage.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/commits-dump.2015-10-03.tar.gz</Url>
  <Properties>
    <Last-Modified>Wed, 09 Dec 2015 18:48:28 GMT</Last-Modified>
    <Etag>0x8D300C95405378B</Etag>
    <Content-Length>189598959329</Content-Length>
    <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
    <Content-Encoding/>
    <Content-Language/>
    <Content-MD5>gzmOYbF+TJGlvQTKPz84PQ==</Content-MD5>
    <Cache-Control/>
    <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
    <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
  </Properties>
</Blob>
```

My question is: how can I parse the `Content-MD5` field (in Ruby/Python) and convert it to what the Linux `md5sum` utility expects?

For this specific file, the equivalent md5sum is: `83398e61b17e4c91a5bd4ca3f3f383d`

Comment: Is your question about how to parse XML in Ruby? Or is it about how to translate `gzmOYbF+TJGlvQTKPz84PQ==` into `36679b78e2aebad1b0bff808e854622d`?

Comment: The latter. I would like to convert `gzmOYbF+TJGlvQTKPz84PQ==` into `36679b78e2aebad1b0bff808e854622d`.

Comment: It's Base64 encoded. Decode it and convert it to hex.

Comment: Yeah but if you decode it you get nothing like the desired md5sum. Either the sum is wrong or there is some other translation step I'm missing.

Comment: So @tadman is correct. However the checksum I provided as an example is wrong. The correct one is `83398e61b17e4c91a5bd4ca3f3f383d`

Answer (score 3):

You can create md5 from local file and compare with azure content md5

Bellow code in python

```
def md5(fname):
   hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
   with open(fname, "rb") as f:
       for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
           hash_md5.update(chunk)
   return base64.b64encode(hash_md5.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the following Ruby code works:

```
irb(main):012:0> require 'base64'
irb(main):013:0> Base64.decode64("gzmOYbF+TJGlvQTKPz84PQ==").each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join == "83398e61b17e4c91a5bd4ca3f3f383d"
=> true
```

Comment: A quicker way to do the hex encoding of binary data is to use [`unpack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) as in `unpack('H*')` in this case.